# Quickest way to apply a formula to an entire column?

Tags: libreoffice

I want each row in column B to be `f( column A)`, so that `b[n]=f(a[n])`. I could go row by row and apply the formula, but is there an easy way to just drag the formula down and have it increment the cells it's referencing automatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying a formula to all cells in a column, not just one at a time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372727/applying-a-formula-to-all-cells-in-a-column-not-just-one-at-a-time)

Comment: The best answer on that question applied to excel, LibreOffice is different though. Ended up hand copy/pasting and altering the formula.

Comment: Copy/Paste a formula is straight forward, but how about the references? Just note that you can prefix for fixed positions with $, e.g. $A$1, or $A1, or A$1 if the copied formula should NOT automatically change one or both of the cell coordinates. See: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/73273/copying-formulae-down-while-only-changing-certain-aspects/

Answer (score 148):

You can follow these steps:

1. Write the formula in the first cell.
2. Click Enter.
3. Click Ctrl+Shift+End. This will select the last right cell used on the worksheet.
4. Ctrl+D. This will fill the value in the remaining cells.

[Source at Zyxware](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/4007/openoffice-calc-how-to-to-apply-a-formula-in-entire-column-without-dragging-in-openoffice-calc)

Comment: I need to press Shift+Enter additionally in step 2, to go back to the first cell. (LibreOffice) For Mac, use Command instead of CTRL.

Comment: This is the way. I have had 30000 rows and couldn't select by mouse. It lasted too long. Thanks!

Comment: You can use Ctrl+Shift+Downarrow to only select cells in the **column**

Comment: @NeroVanbiervliet Correct. This answer should be edited.

Comment: @SurpriseDog
> Click Ctrl+Shift+End. This will select the **last right cell used on the worksheet.**

Comment: The question asks for selecting a column, not for selecting the "last right cell"

Comment: @SurpriseDog as you may see by the up votes in the answer, people understood

Comment: Looks like this only works if you have no filters applied.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Downarrow also  works in Google Sheets

Comment: The answer by Bastiaan Wakkie actually answers the question as posed: more easily filling just the column, just to the end of the data. As noted by SupriseDoc, this answer does something different, if there are columns to the right.

Comment: Just tried this and it doesn't fill the formula as of the latest LibreOffice version.
Ctrl+Shift+End will select remaining cells in the column, but Ctrl+D does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Oh, really? Didn't see in the latest libreOffice version, I'll check i out

Answer (score 40):

This worked for me,

1. Write the formula in the top cell of a column.
2. Copy this cell
3. Select all of the rest of cells in the column.  You can do this by clicking on the top cell and shift clicking on the bottom cell so the scrolling is really quick
4. With all of the cells selected select Paste.  The formula will be copied to all of the currently selected cells, but will be adjusted according to its position in the sheet.

Comment: this works better CTRL+D to fill the values did not work for me

Answer (score 25):

A slightly modified version of what Victor Gazotti proposed:

1. Write the formula in the cell.
2. Click on the cell with the formula.
3. Scroll to the last element in the column.
4. Click on the last row in this column while holding Shift button, so that the column becomes highlighted, while the first row in the selection contains the formula.
5. Click CTRL+D and the formula will be spread for the whole selection.

Comment: This is a better answer than Victor's. Simpler (no 3-button combos) and works in more cases (doesn't assume pressing Enter leaves you on the current cell).

Answer (score 16):

There is an other easier way! (at least in libreoffice 6.4.3.2)

1. Create your formula next to the column with values (say A values, B formula)
2. Select the cell with the new Formula
3. [ctrl+shift] + double left-click the fill handle of the selected cell

This will copy your formula down in row B till the last filled cell in row A

(EDIT: Adjusted the solution to double left-click in point 3)

Comment: In 6.3.4.2, you have to double-click the fill handle.

Comment: in 3 + right click didn't work for me, it had to left double-click

Answer (score 5):

*Quickest way to manipulate whole rows or columns is using an **array formula***

As for why you would want to use array formulas vs regular formulas has some points [here](https://superuser.com/a/879070/911646) -

> array formulas can be a bit faster, but a bit more difficult for editing.. you can't easily overwrite array formula ranges *(which is good for safety)*.

Check my answer to the similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52119910/9049673

--Copied verbatim here for ease--

From your question it seems that you are trying to apply the same formula on whole row (or column) of cells and show the result on another row (or column).

The best way to do this is to use something called **array formulas** or array functions (in libre office). This link has very good explanation - https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions

The way you would implement this in your case is

`Type this formula in cell D1`

```
=C1:C30 *48
```

`and press ctrl + shift + enter`

The formula now looks like this with the flower braces `{..}`

```
={C1:C30 *48}
```

and the formula gets applied all the way from D1 to D30.

You can even extrapolate the same concept to a whole matrix (for example: `A1:C10`)

(The way to tell excel/open office/ libre office that you wrote an array formula is to press `ctrl + shift + enter`. Never press `enter` on habit while editing the array formula, as that will break the array function and convert it to a regular function)